# Explicit instantiation of templated lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I just came across a problem to explicit instantiate a templated lambda. The below code does not compile, but I can't figure out what's wrong in this case:

```
        [&]<auto... II>(std::index_sequence<II...>) {
            auto check = [&]<auto I>(){
            };
            (check<II>(),...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
```

Compiler error (gcc trunk: 11.0.0):

```
rswitch.cc: In lambda function:
rswitch.cc:42:28: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
42 |                 (check<II>(),...);
|                            ^
rswitch.cc:42:26: error: binary expression in operand of fold-expression
42 |                 (check<II>(),...);
```

I looks like I had to use the template disambiguation like this:

```
        [&]<auto... II>(std::index_sequence<II...>) {
            auto check = [&]<auto I>(){
            };
            (this->template check<II>(),...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
```

Are there other ways to express this?

Comment: Instead of call `(check<II>(),...);`, you need to specify the template value for the `operator()`: `(check. template operator()<II>(),...);`.

Comment: This is not an explicit *instantiation*, but rather explicit template arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`check` itself is not a template. It is an object, of an unspecified closure type, that contains

```
template<auto I> void operator()();
```

The *member function* is the template.

The error is due to the attempt at supplying template arguments to `check`. Which is not a template itself, again. The template parameters of a lambda's function call operator need to be deducible (even if they are named), for the function call syntax to work. That hasn't changed with C++20.

The only way to specify the parameters explicitly is the pretty ugly

```
check.template operator()<II>()
```

But instead it may be better to make it deducible.

```
[&]<auto... II>(std::index_sequence<II...>) {
    auto check = [&]<auto I>(std::integral_constant<decltype(I), I>){
    };
    (check(std::integral_constant<decltype(II), II>{}),...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
```

Specifying `size_t` explicitly is also an option instead of using `decltype(I)`.